# How long does it take for a listener to catch a fired event?

Tags: java, events, listener

Let's say a listener was added to a component then fired (class implements this listener):

```
newButton(); //pretend this is called somewhere

public void newButton() {
  JButton button = new JButton("test");
  button.addStuffListener(this);
  button.fireStuffEvent();
  System.out.println("action over"); //getting here
}


public void stuffPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  System.out.println("action fired");
}
```

How long does it take for the **'action over'** line to print? How about the **'action fired'**? Does Java create another thread when an event is fired? If one does not always fire after another, what's a safe way to make sure they do?

Comment: @GhostCat yeah sorry took so long haha, credit is due

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Java "UI use cases", the thing to know about is the [Event Dispatcher Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). That thread is responsible for well, dispatching events.

So a **listener** method is invoked *by* the ED thread. Which translates to: whenever your listener method is doing more close-to-nothing, it has to push that work *somehow* into another thread. Otherwise your listener activity starts "freezing" your application. Because the ED thread is busy doing listener work, instead of dispatching events.

For the "when" of "listener being called": as soon as the ED thread is able to. Events get in, and at some point the ED thread dispatches them. We are not talking about a **real time** software stack here, therefore there are *no* guarantees how long that might take.

And for completeness: when we are talking about a "test" setup, were you actually do not use Swing/AWT buttons, and "UI events" - but you just have your own objects, calling each other: then there is only one thread, doing all things in sequence.